# WPF Templated button - no click event

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to design a button that has a dashed border all around and an image in the middle. The ideal hit test would be on the image itself, but not a requirement. My problem is that I can't get the click event to fire. It's probably a hit test problem, but I can't figure it out.

In addition to the obvious onClick on the button, I tried MouseEvents on the image, ButtonBase.Click on the Stackpanel, Border.InputBindings on the border .. I thought setting Background=Transparent would do it, but no go.

Here's the xaml:

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" Click="Button_Click_1">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border Background="Transparent" Grid.Row="0" Margin="30,50" CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="4">
                        <Border.BorderBrush>
                            <VisualBrush>
                                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                    <Rectangle StrokeDashArray="4 2"
                                Stroke="#CEAC2D"
                                StrokeThickness="4"
                                RadiusX="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}, Path=CornerRadius.TopRight}"
                                RadiusY="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}, Path=CornerRadius.BottomLeft}"
                                Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}, Path=ActualWidth}"
                                Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}, Path=ActualHeight}"/>
                                </VisualBrush.Visual>
                            </VisualBrush>
                        </Border.BorderBrush>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center" ButtonBase.Click="Button_Click_1">
                            <Button Height="30" Width="30" Content="Start"/> // just a test button to see if it works
                            <Image Source="/Images/uploadIcon.png" Height="180"/>
                            <TextBlock Margin="0,20,0,0" Foreground="#CEAC2D" Text="Drag Folder or Click to Browse" FontFamily="Lato" FontSize="27" 
                           FontWeight="SemiBold"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
```

Comment: It works just fine for me if I remove the `Button` element and the `ButtonBase.Click` attribute from the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you trying to set the whole thing as the button's template? If you only want the image bit actually clickable then set that as a button's control template and place it inside a regular visual tree:

```
<Border Background="Transparent" Grid.Row="0" Margin="30,50" CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="4">
    <Border.BorderBrush>
        <VisualBrush>
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Rectangle StrokeDashArray="4 2"
                Stroke="#CEAC2D"
                StrokeThickness="4"
                RadiusX="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}, Path=CornerRadius.TopRight}"
                RadiusY="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}, Path=CornerRadius.BottomLeft}"
                Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}, Path=ActualWidth}"
                Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}, Path=ActualHeight}"/>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </Border.BorderBrush>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Click="Button_Click_1" Cursor="Hand">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Image Source="/Images/uploadIcon.png" Height="180"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
        <TextBlock Margin="0,20,0,0" Foreground="#CEAC2D" Text="Drag Folder or Click to Browse" FontFamily="Lato" FontSize="27" 
            FontWeight="SemiBold"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

Comment: Np. You'd also now set the click handler on the button itself of course instead of the StackPanel, I've updated the code to reflect that.